# How to take the sum of several selected rows in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, aggregate

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
         id  StateCode Year  Data
1      AB123        AZ 1960  100
2      XY567        AZ 1961  200
3      CB666        AZ 1962  300
4      PT788        AZ 1963  400
5      AG999        AZ 1964  500
```

I want to take the sum of `df$Data` based on the row ids. For example, sum of id 'AB123', id 'CB666' and id 'XY567' should return 600. How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with base R:

```
ids <- c("AB123", "XY567", "CB666")

with(subset(df, id %in% ids), sum(Data))

#[1] 600
```

Data:

```
text <- "         id  StateCode Year  Data
1      AB123        AZ 1960  100
2      XY567        AZ 1961  200
3      CB666        AZ 1962  300
4      PT788        AZ 1963  400
5      AG999        AZ 1964  500"

df <- read.table(text = text, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter(id %in% c("AB123", "CB666", "XY567")) %>% #filter the rows
    pull(Data) %>% #pull the column 'Data'
    sum #get the sum
#[1] 600
```

Answer (score 1):

We can filter the data frame using `%in%` on `id` and then sum the `Data` column.

```
sum(dat[dat$id %in% c("AB123", "CB666", "XY567"), ]$Data)
# [1] 600
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "         id  StateCode Year  Data
1      AB123        AZ 1960  100
2      XY567        AZ 1961  200
3      CB666        AZ 1962  300
4      PT788        AZ 1963  400
5      AG999        AZ 1964  500",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```